# Setting the width of an element 100% relative to parent of the parent container

Tags: php, html, css

How do i set the width of an element relative to the width of the parent parent element?

I'm using a slider plugin that requires the direct parent container to be larger to contain all the divs with overflow: hidden set. I need to set the element to have a 100% width in relation to the width of the parent parent container.

How do i go about doing this? Any help appreciated

Comment: just set the parent to `width:100%;` so that it's the same size as the grandparent.

Comment: I'm trying to use the touch slider plugin: mobilizetoday.com/freebies/touchslider/basic#section-css and it states that the stretch have to be at 9999px. I tried using yours but my divs don't go beyond if i don't have the stretch width initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The slider pluggin is most likely already doing a .parent() so you just need to append another .parent() to it like so: .parent().parent()

Answer (score 0):

- The "parent of parent" has set dimensions (I think you already did it).
- The "parent" which expands needs to have `white-space:nowrap` so that stuff spanning horizontally don't wrap to the next row. Also, it must *not* have `width` so that the slides' `width` is relative to "parent of parent".
- The "slides" need to have `display:inline-block` so that they are allowed to sit side-by side, because divs normally clear both before and after.

You can do it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/arc9txr1/). The parent has a thick black border. The children are as wide as "parent of parent" but they manage to "spill out" horizontally, courtesy of "parent". The trick here is to *not set the width of "parent"* so that `width` is relative to the nearest ancestor having a `width` which is "parent of parent".

Lastly, a "gap" between elements is a common problem for elements with `display:inline-block`. A common solution is to comment out the whitespace, or just have the elements directly be next to each other, like `</div><div>`.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="stretch">
        <div class="item item1">1</div><!--
        --><div class="item item2">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.stretch{
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.item{
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.item1{
    background: green;
}

.item2{
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the touch slider plugin: http://www.mobilizetoday.com/freebies/touchslider/basic#section-css and it states that the stretch have to be at 9999px. I tried using yours but my divs don't go beyond if i don't have the stretch width initialized.